# Can I create iscsi targets manually by editing the targetcli configuration file?

Tags: centos7, iscsi

Rather than going through the tedious process of setting up about 20 backstore block devices and targets one at a time in targetcli, I'm looking at the config .json file, and it seems like it'd be a pretty straightforward matter of just editing that in a text editor and importing it.

There are some items I'm not clear on. For example. in the backstores section of the file, each block device has a "wwn" key:

```
"wwn": "2e80f5cb-050a-4ca1-94b1-49ea7dfa953f"
```

and in the targets section, the luns have an "alias" key:

```
"alias": "1d24f065e5",
```

I'm not sure if the values for these are pulled from somewhere else in the system or if they're generated randomly by targetcli. Is it ok for me to replace these with any unique ID I want, or is this something that needs to be referenced to something specific?

Comment: Well, the [WWN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Name) is obvious, but I have no idea what the alias is.

Comment: Ok, so for WWN, the value in the config file (which was generated by targetcli) doesn't match the value in /dev/disk/by-id. For example, in the config file, the WWN for /dev/sdb2 is: b7c84f95-86d4-4eb9-b1b1-9bfa2fbb34b6  ...but in /dev/disk/by-id it's scsi-2a9f7b97f00d00000-part2